# Delphi, Copy string to Byte array

Tags: delphi, string, arrays, delphi-7

what i have works, but im looking if there is a faster way to copy a string into a pByteArray

from sysutils

```
  PByteArray = ^TByteArray;
  TByteArray = array[0..32767] of Byte;
```

assume **a** and **s** are setup correctly

```
 a:   pByteArray;
 s:   string;
```

is there a fast way to do this, ie something like copy

```
  for i := 1 TO Length(s) - 1 do
   a^[i] := Ord(s[i]);
```

delphi 7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Beware using the Move.  If you are using Delphi 2009, it may fail.  Instead, use this:

Move(s[1], a^, Length(s) * SizeOf(Char));

You may also use class TEncoding in SysUtils.pas (Delphi 2009/2010++ only) to perform the task.

Comment: The for loop doesn't execute if length(s) is zero. To be fully equivalent you need to add a check for if length(s). Added.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply cast it:

```
  a := @s[1];
```

The other way around is:

```
  s := PChar(a);
```

Comment: That doesn't copy anything, and it makes `a` point to something that isn't what its type says it is.

Comment: True (I assumed the purpose was to access the a string as a bytearray or vice vera)

Answer (score 2):

never mind, found it

```
 Move(s[1], a^, Length(s));
```

Comment: Remember to check Length(s) <= SizeOf(a), or you risk a buffer overflow - a string may be bigger than a TByteArray.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `move` procedure just like in this [example](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Move)